# How do I import and export more than one numpy arrays?

Tags: data, numpy

I have four numpy arrays `X_train`, `y_train`, `X_test`, `y_test`. I want to know how do I export and import them all together.
 
 I tried exporting them using `numpy.save("data.npy",list, [X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test])`, data.npy file is created and then I tried importing using `np_data = numpy.load("data.npy", allow_pickle=True)`.
and now I can't access the data. 
`np_data` says `array(<class 'list'>, dtype=object)` 
`np_data[0]` says `IndexError: too many indices for array: array is 0-dimensional, but 1 were indexed` 
and also I don't understand why `allow_pickle` is necessary ?

Comment: Have you tried using [`numpy.savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html), i.e. `numpy.savez("data.npy", X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test)`?

Comment: Yeah, `numpy.savez` did the job. Didn't know about it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [`numpy.savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) to save multiple numpy arrays to a single file. This would look as follows in your case:

```
numpy.savez("data.npy", X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test)
```